# Python2 reflection: Strange behavior of __import__()

Tags: python, reflection, python-import

I need to have a generic script which takes *some_module.function* as argument and executes it.
I wrote a solution for this (has to be Python-2.4 compatible...):

```
def get_function(f_name):
    """Return function from library..."""
    lib, f = f_name.rsplit('.', 1)
    module = getattr(__import__(lib), lib.rsplit('.', 1)[-1])
    return getattr(module, f)

f = get_function('my_libs.testlib.test_function')
# finally, this executes the function
f()
```

My question is:

Why do I have to do the *`getattr()`* after *`__import__()`*?

Turns out `module = __import__('lib')` will have the namespace *above* the one of *lib*.

So when I wanted to call a function from *lib*, say *lib.f_x*, I would have to do it like:

```
module = __import__('lib')
module.lib.f_x()
```

instead of what I would expect:

```
module = __import__('lib')
module.f_x()
```

Or use the contruct with `getattr()` as above.
Why is that?

Comment: you do realise you can pass a function as easily as any other object?

Comment: sure. the point of this code is that you don't know and need not know the name of the module/function beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given in [the documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)

> When the name variable is of the form `package.module` , normally, the top-level package (the name up till the first dot) is returned, not the module named by name.

Why? Because lets say you asked it to import `blah.something` , what should be returned would be `blah` with `something` being an attribute inside `blah` (hence the requirement to use `getattr`) .

A simple solution to this should be -

```
def get_function(f_name):
    """Return function from library..."""
    lib = f_name.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
    modl = __import__(lib)
    comps = f_name.split('.')[1:]
    for comp in comps:
        modl = getattr(modl,comp)
    return modl
```

The above also works if you are simply importing module , or a function from a module or a package, etc.